# Dimensionality reduction of the domain of f(x)

Tags: linear-algebra, high-dimensional, data-analysis, model

I'm wondering if there is something analogous to a PCA for data sets where there is a dependent variable.  (Though I am interested in any method of dimensionality reduction, PCA is just an example.)  A PCA will take a 64-dimensional data set (say) and might return 4 dimensions which explain 95% of the variance.  From a 4-point vector in the new space and the covariance matrix you could recover the original record with pretty good fidelity in this example.

So what about the case where x has 64 dimensions, and the data have the form (x, y) where y is a measurement?  Is there something similar, that will let me predict y from a lower dimensional set of inputs?  I.e., y $\approx$ g(x'), where dim(x') < dim(x), and there is a map m: x' $\mapsto$ x.  (y' = g(x') and another map p: y' $\mapsto$ y is fine too.)

Often what people do in this situation is choose a model such as a GLM and do a partial regression, eliminating those dimensions where the regression coefficients are close to 0.  However I'm looking for a method which does not assume any kind of model at all.  Do these exist?

The image below illustrates an extreme case of this.  Nominally the data is 2-dimensional, but the y-dimension is just a bit of 0-mean noise--z can be estimated well enough on the basis of x alone.  So I'm wondering if there's a technique which will derive this, here but also cases where the redundancy is less obvious.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! I think what you are looking for is called "nonlinear dimensionality reduction" or "manifold learning"; this is a *very* active research area - take a look at the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction).

Comment: For reference: also posted at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/906017 ([cross-posting is usually discouraged on the SE network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068); in my opinion the question would be slightly more on topic here, although the community on Cross Validated would have even more expertise, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110185/reference-for-dimension-reduction-techniques)

Comment: @ChristianClason I've gone ahead and deleted the Math.Stackexchange version.  I posted there and then discovered this site, and being unsure about where it was better suited, I decided to violate SE etiquette for a little bit and leave it in both places.  I'll check out CV, thanks.

Comment: @ChristianClason nonlinear dimensionality reduction looks promising, not surprised to find out it's a whole subfield, thanks.

Comment: That's OK; in the absence of a strong community consensus, some common sense is advised. But it's important to a) wait a few days before cross-posting (otherwise it looks a bit like carpet-bombing), b) make sure it's really on-topic at both sites (and not just marginally - there are higher standards for cross-posts) , and c) cross-link and keep up-to-date all duplicates (so people don't waste their time with an answer you already received on the other site).

Comment: This would be better on Cross Validated. Also, bear in mind that in the expression $y\approx g(x')$, the sign "$\approx$" can mean a thousand different things. So there is a fair amount of work to be done to make this precise enough to turn this into a "scientific computation" problem.

Comment: @Kirill Thanks I will try a version 2.0 of this question there.  It looks like this NLDR is in general not interested in preserving the 'functional' nature of data, as I am, so there might be room to add to the answers already present.  Though perhaps it's just a question of interpretation.  But re the expression, I just mean |y - g(x')| $\approx$ 0, and since y, g(x') are scalars I can't believe that's really so vague.

Comment: $|y-g(x')|$ is a scalar for each specific value of $x'$, but it's really a function of $x'$. It's common, for example, for some parts of the domain of $x'$ to be more important than others, in which case you place more weight on $|y-g(x')|$ being lower there than somewhere else. You likely have no reason to expect the residual $|y-g(x')|$ to be uniformly small everywhere in the domain.

Comment: I'm not sure it's meaningful to ask for an answer that "does not assume any kind of model." There's pretty much _always_ an implied model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at active subspaces, e.g., Active Subspace Methods in Theory and Practice: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/130916138

And a PDF here:
http://inside.mines.edu/~pconstan/docs/constantine-asm.pdf

I have a SIAM book (Active Subspaces: Emerging Ideas for Dimension Reduction in Parameter Studies) coming out in March.

Suppose $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}$. One model that addresses what you're looking for is

$$
f(x) \approx g(W^T x),
$$

where $W$ is $m\times n$, and $g$ is a function that maps $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. In active subspaces, $W$ is the first $n$ eigenvectors of the symmetric, positive semidefinite matrix,

$$
C = \int (\nabla f)(\nabla f)^T\rho\,dx,
$$

where $\rho=\rho(x)$ is a given density function on the domain. The paper I linked to discusses how to estimate $W$ and how to construct $g$---along with error estimates.

Here's a video of the process of exploiting active subspaces for constructing response surfaces (i.e., surrogate models or metamodels): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJvKzjT6lmY

However, in the figure you show, the function is noisy, so the exact gradient might not be the best choice; those eigenvectors will pick up directions associated with the high frequency noise. In the statistics literature, your problem goes by the name [sufficient dimension reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_dimension_reduction), which is set in the context of regression (i.e., supervised learning) with one set of variables designated as *predictors* (the independent variables) and the other set designated *responses* (the dependent variable). Take a look at Dennis Cook's book [Regression Graphics](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471193658.html), which is my favorite overview of the field. And yes, sufficient dimension reduction is an entire subfield of statistics.

EDIT: I updated the video link, the book is now published by [SIAM](http://bookstore.siam.org/sl02/), and we have a new active subspaces [website](http://www.activesubspaces.org).

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be helpful to perform a tensor product spline interpolation or rather, approximation by least squares as the data is noisy, e.g., by using Matlab's [Curve fitting toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/curvefit/approximation-by-tensor-product-splines.html), and see whether the coefficients along certain dimensions tend to zero, meaning it's a low (hopefully 0-) order polynomial along that dimension.